# Bounded or unbounded function $g(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2t}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

> $$g(t)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-2t}}$$

Find the domain and if the function is bounded or unbonded.

Comment: Just from knowing the limits for $t\to 0,t\to -\infty$ you can't say anything about the function being bounded yet. (You have a continuous function, so...)

Comment: If your function is $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-2t}}$ No! Your domain is false.

Comment: @MyGlasses keep in mind that the domain of the function is **given** as $D=(-\infty,0]$.

Comment: No, sorry the domain was not given. How is it not correct? t cannot be greater than zero but it can be less than zero and equal to zero.

Comment: Say $1-2t\geq0$ means $t\leq\dfrac12$.

Comment: Then you should give the correct question with every information you have given. If you have $D=(-\infty,0]$, then the function will be bounded, for other possible domains that might not be the case.

Comment: So the domain should be D = (−∞, 1/2) U (1/2, 0]

Comment: That doesn't really make sense as $(1/2,0]\subset (-\infty,1/2)$. And if that is in fact the correct domain, then your function is not bounded. (Also we'd have to discuss what you mean by (1/2,0] as $1/2>0$).

Comment: @MyGlasses I did not delete anything. Please don't accuse me of something like that. If you check the revision summary you will see that the OP removed his attempts, I simply corrected your mistake of writing $g(x)$ instead of $g(t)$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For given function $g(t)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-2t}}$ the domain is $(-\infty,\dfrac12)$. If $t_1\leq t_2$ then $1-2t_1\geq1-2t_2$ and this shows $g(t_1)\leq g(t_2)$ so the function is increasing. As you said 
$$\lim_{t\to-\infty}g(t)=0$$
so the function is bounded below, and
$$\lim_{t\to\frac12^-}g(t)=+\infty$$
shows the function is not bounded above.
[image]

Comment: So the function is both bounded and not bounded? We were taught that if at least one of the domain values equals infinity then the function is unbounded, is that wrong?

Comment: if the definitions says the function is bounded if there exist a real $M$ such that $|f(t)|\leq M$. so you are right.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, truly appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome!